# Missing dll error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I am getting this error that `Microsoft.exchange.webservices` can not be  added to GAC while deploying solution.

We have got solution from other team which work on their environment. When we trying to set up development environment for same, it's giving above error.

It's SharePoint 2013 version.

What might be the cause for this?

Checked Visual Studio versions and other things already.

Any help will be great for this.

TIA.

Comment: it sounds like you are deploying a custom solution. If it is a MS solution or open source solution please provide the details. If it is custom made you have to ask the developer.

Comment: if you are configuring site mailboxes in SharePoint Server, you may refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/configure-site-mailboxes-in-sharepoint for install procedure.

Comment: We are on our own. No developer to explain. Its custom solution with timer job

Comment: maybe you can ask other team how to install?

Comment: Have you tried deploying without -GACDeployment parameter with Install-SPSolution command to see if it helps?

Comment: Use GACUtil tool to try to deploy your assembly. If it still throws an error, you will atleast know the error in detail.

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message you are getting? Is it from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Remove from wsp not from GAC. delete entry from the manifest file of wsp.

Reset Timer and IIS services. Try Gacutil.exe to uninstall dll

You can refer to these two similar situations:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5b38abb9-e85d-4c0d-bc3f-92c28a9fb7ad/error-cannot-add-the-specified-assembly-to-the-global-assembly-cache?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/4c1a146d-c41b-43b4-b915-90295d047ce0/error-occured-in-deployment-step-add-solution-error-cannot-add-the-specified-assembly-to-the?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious